# JQuery: Open popup after hovering

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ASP.NET with C#

I need to display a popup panel (doesn't have to be a panel) when i hover over a UI element.

The user may click on buttons on the panel which will envoke Ajax calls

How can i go about this? Any code samples?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JQuery UI Dialog and trigger the event on mouseover? Like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("UI ELEMENT").mouseover(function() {
        $("#panel").dialog({ autoOpen: true });
    });
});
```

for more info on the Dialog or Jquery UI see here: [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/

I'm not entirely sure what you need.